# Java: get content of MIME multipart BodyPart

Tags: java, mime, multipart

I'm trying to retrieve content of MIME multipart using BodyPart as follow

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = null;
MimeMultipart mp = new MimeMultipart(new ByteArrayDataSource(inputStream, contentType));
int count = mp.getCount();
baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    BodyPart bodyPart = mp.getBodyPart(i);
    Object content = bodyPart.getContent();
    if (content instanceof InputStream) {

         // process inputStream

     }

bodyPart.writeTo(MIMEbaos);
String attachment = MIMEbaos.toString();
```

}

But `bodyPart.getContent()` is providing the same InputStream as whole MIME message when I expect just a content (without content-type, boundaries etc) when `attachment` contains whole MIME multipart body section including content-type, etc.

`InputStream` is from

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
msg.writeTo(baos);

byte[] bytes = baos.toByteArray();
InputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);
```

where `msg` is `SOAPMessage` MIME type as MTOM

Comment: What, exactly, are the expected results?  What are you seeing instead?

Comment: @VGR `bodyPart.getDisposition()` comes as null and `bodyPart.getContent()` comes as Byte Array Input Stream not a String. I'm expecting, at least for `bodyPart.getContent()` to see current content (plain) of the MIME multipart w/o related headers.

Comment: Where does `inputStream` come from?  Are you sure it’s a multi-part MIME message?

Comment: @VGR Yeah, incoming message is a MTOM and I need to get a content for each of part of it. Added more code to the OP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have ended up with

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = null;
MimeMultipart mp = new MimeMultipart(new ByteArrayDataSource(inputStream, contentType));
int count = mp.getCount();
baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    BodyPart bodyPart = mp.getBodyPart(i);
    Object content = bodyPart.getContent();
    String content = new String(read(bodyPart));

    String partContentType =  bodyPart.getContentType();
}

bodyPart.writeTo(MIMEbaos);
String attachment = MIMEbaos.toString();

    private static byte[] read(BodyPart bodyPart) throws MessagingException, IOException
    {
        InputStream inputStream = bodyPart.getInputStream();
        ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        int data = 0;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

        while ((data = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            outputStream.write(buffer, 0, data);
        }

        return outputStream.toByteArray();
    }
```